# Saving Calculated Data when using rails_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

In my project i have **product** model and **stock_in** model, using **rails_admin** gem how can i update a quantity of a product automatically when new stock_in is created for that product?

Comment: Please post some code. E.g. your models and db schema so we can see what attributes you have already.

Comment: You can define an `after_create` hook on `StockIn` that updates the associated `product` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code, it's hard to give you anything more than general advice.

You don't need to do this through `rails_admin` because Rails already has hooks.

Assuming your `Product` and `StockIn` models are related:

```rb
class Product
  has_many :stock_ins
end

class StockIn
  belongs_to :product
end
```

You can just use an `after_create` hook on `StockIn`:

```rb
class StockIn
  belongs_to :product

  after_create :update_product_quantity

  ...

  private

  def update_product_quantity
    product.update(quantity: self.quantity)
  end
end
```